# Stairs railing restoration

Tags: wood, stairs, railing, polish

I have noticed that some of my stair railing coating has been chipping off, clearly due to wear and tear uses. I have an elderly person living in the house and has to hold the railing right to use stair. Is there Polish or coating that I can use to restore the look of it? Attaching pictures for the reference. First time homeowner in the States so really appreciate your help. Thank you so much in advanced. [image]

Answer (score 2):

Yes, sand it down and re-apply a suitable finish.

Looks like it is the damage from a ring worn by someone though, given how is is on the "corner"...

Comment: or until you are ready to sand it down, find a varathane and just feather it into the areas that are most chipped.